# How to invoke Html button control in repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

Below is my code,can anyone please guide me in invoking the html button on repeater control.

Mark up:

```
      <asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server" onitemcommand="rptList_ItemCommand1">
 <HeaderTemplate>
    <table id="tbllist">
        <tr>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th width="100%" align="left">Item</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><%# Eval("Quantity")%></td>
            <td align="left"><%# Eval("ItemName")%></td>
            <td align="center"><input id="Button1" runat="server" commandname="btnAdd" type="button" value="Addtocart" /></td>
        </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

.CS file code:

```
   protected void rptList_ItemCommand1(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "btnAdd")
        {
            Response.Write("hello,I am a button.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You forget runat="server" tag in input. Better option use the ASP:Button control place of input as button type

Comment: Thanks @SaroopTrivedi for responding,I am using HTML control and eventhough I have added runat= "server" when I click on button nothing happening.can you please suggest me do I need to add anything on .cs file

Comment: Kittu: U need to add CommandName and search that Commandname into ItemCommand event

Comment: Hi @SaroopTrivedi,Eventhough I have added the Commandname not seeing any response.If you can please guide me I have edited my code above.

Comment: why you use html input?

Comment: Use asp:Button COntrol at place of  HTML Input

Comment: since I am using Javascript on page load I am using html control .thank u I have resolved the error.

Comment: How you resolved this problem

Answer (score 0):

You have used input without `runat="server"`, You need to add runat="server" to make a button server button control and perform `postback`

Change

```
<input id="btnAddtocart" type="button" value="Addtocart" />
```

To

```
<input id="btnAddtocart" runat="server" type="button" value="Addtocart" />
```

Use `asp:button` instead of `input type="button"` if you do not have any particular reason for using it.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnAddtocart"  runat="server" Text="Addtocart" CommandName="Addtocart"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Adil for responding,I am using HTML control and eventhough I have added runat= "server" when I click on button nothing happening.can you please suggest me do I need to add anything on .cs file

Comment: If you added runat then it should have worked, tell me where and how you bind the repeater?

Answer (score 0):

You have used input without runat="server"

Change

```
<input id="btnAddtocart" type="button" value="Addtocart" />
```

To

```
<input id="btnAddtocart" runat="server" type="button" value="Addtocart"  CommandName="CommandName"/>
```

Use asp:button instead of input type="button"

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnAddtocart"  runat="server" CommandName="CommandName"/>
```